# Always logging an ID

Tags: slf4j, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

In my debug logs I'm seeing this desirable id "0x277ec1de" or similar for each request, thus numbering the request in a very convenient way:

```
  2018-12-11 09:58:55.490 DEBUG 11868 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler          : [id: 0x277ec1de, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8443 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:51951] HANDSHAKEN: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
  2018-12-11 09:58:55.492 DEBUG 11868 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [277ec1de] HTTP GET "/v1/voice/selectCaching?q=*:*&rows=100"
```

If I could re-use this ID in my own code, I'd then be able to pull out everything that happened before an errormessage, and only of the errormessage, disregarding all the thousand other requests, that happen in parallel.
Does onyone have a clue, how this can be done?
I'm using Spring-Boot 2.1.1, with netty as embedded webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that log prefix information from the server exchange with `ServerWebExchange#getLogPrefix()`. Same thing applies to the client side with `ClientRequest#logPrefix()`.

See the [Spring WebFlux reference documentation on log ids](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-logging-id).